# How do I fix "Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file" in log file (reported by SonarQube scanner)?

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm running a SonarSource analysis for a C# project on a Jenkins server. 
The log shows several of these messages:

> Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file. Please check that VS 2015 Update 1 (or later) is installed.

There is no Visual Studio on this Jenkins server. I'm just using MSBuild (14.0.25123.0 - this should be the version you get with VS 2015 Update 2) and "SonarQube scanner for MSBuild 2.0". SonarQube is 5.3, Sonar C# plugin 5.1-RC3

Answer (score 1):

v1.0 version of Roslyn (*Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.**) that shipped with Visual Studio 2015 had a bug which meant that the json error log files produced by the compiler might contain invalid json. The bug was fixed in Roslyn v1.1, which shipped with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

The MSBuild Scanner has special-case code to detect and fix the invalid json so the error log could be parsed and the file uploaded. The special-case code is quite specific, in that it will only attempt to fix json file produce by the v1.0 compiler (when the error log header has *productVersion*=*1.0.0* and *toolName*=*Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler*).

The error message you are seeing refers to Visual Studio 2015 since that is generally how users will have acquired the compiler, although the real issue is the version of compiler being used.

The fact you are seeing the message strongly suggests that your build is using Roslyn v1.0, which is odd since MSBuild 14.0.25123.0 shipped with Roslyn v1.2. Check the *productVersion* in the error log file that is being produced.

Also, trying running a build with diagnostic logging turned on (e.g. by passing */v:diag* as a command line argument to MSBuild). The detailed output will include the location of *Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll* that is being used; check the version of the dll, and the version of the *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll* files in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried raising a question through official [Jira](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU/https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) tracker? I think it would be most efficient way of getting a feedback about C# SonarQube plug-in.

Comment: Thanks, @luka5z. According to SonarQube google group, support questions like this one should be asked on StackOverflow and tagged with "sonarqube", that's why I did it this way. I will try other ways if I get no answers here.